# Did I need an alignment?

Tags: alignment

I got new tires and had free alignment check.

The guy came back and said the passenger rear is way off.  Note that I did get a flat the previous day and rode with a spare for very minimal miles. To fix the camber, it would have been really expensive (300+), but he recommended not fixing that but said the toe was really off on the rear passenger and he recommended an alignment.

I had him do it, but the tech came out afterwards and said after he did the regular alignment, the camber reading was fine.  So, I'm wondering if the toe was really that bad as well.  Maybe their machine wasn't calibrated correctly?  Also, now that I'm researching alignments, is fixing tie settings a true alignment?  The rear passenger toe before shows -0.03.  Not really sure what this means, but it was outside the ok range.

Comment: On the rear, I believe almost anything outside of straight up is bad. The rear needs to track correctly, which should be straight up ... at least this is my thinking. I've never been an alignment tech, so cannot say for sure. The fronts need to have slight toe in or the car will wander.

Comment: The alignment places I go to give me a printout of before and after numbers. If you have that, post it here.

Comment: -0.03 toe (aka"toe in") on a rear is negligable.  A vector called "Thrust Angle" is more important.  Like tlhIngan mentioned, a printout would be very helpful.  There are alignment settings outside of straight tow, and it usually depends on which end(s) of the car are driven, and would deflect elastomer mountings if said rear wheels were transmitting power.  These things didn't use to be very adjustable in the days of solid axles, but now are a crucial adjustment for AWD and RWD cars with fully independent rear suspensions.  Thrust angle describes the interaction between the front and rear.

Comment: @SteveRacer Many new cars still have a solid beam rear suspension design, these have no adjustments whatsoever - if something is out of alignment here then there is something structural bent or the mounting is worn out. To the OP: The print outs and make/model of the vehicle would be helpful in asnwering this question.

Comment: @DizzyFool  Probably correct, but unknown until the OP reveals what vehicle it is.  And even with a "modern" solid beam axle, although individual rear wheel alignment is not easy (you can usually still *shim* camber/toe), there are new bushing and/or eccentric kits for the trailing arm pivots to remedy severe thrust angle issues.  But your point, if it applies, is quite valid. -0.03 is probably somewhere in the measuring error range anyway, depending on the equipment.  Interesting (if you have money to burn) to get a printout from a completely different rack and shop and compare the results.

Comment: @SteveRacer also correct, sadly I've never seen regular alignment places go far enough to use shims to correct minor misalignment, especially on older economy cars which tend to be the ones that have solid trailing arms. I attribute this to the "disposable" nature of economy cars and the lack of vehicle maintenance culture where I live.

Comment: @DizzyFool  Most cars I work on have *never* seen an alignment rack, unless it was "sold" to them as absolutely necessary when getting new tires. The "disposable" and "lack of maintenance culture" I suspect is largely generational, and not necessarily geographic.